# How to access the value of constant in settings.py

Tags: python, django

I'd like ask about how to access the value of a constant declared in setting.py the following way:

```
PAYMENT_VARIANTS = {
'redsys': ('payments_redsys.RedsysProvider', {
    'merchant_code': '123456789',
    'terminal': '1',
    'shared_secret': 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
    'currency': '978',
})
```

}

I can import:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

But, how I can access the value of field 'currency' or other at this level.

Thanks, regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can do for example:

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    # Do something
```

In your case would be something like:

```
settings.PAYMENT_VARIANTS['redsys']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the PAYMENT_VARIANTS dictionary using `settings.PAYMENT_VARIANTS` and can access the key `currency` like this

```
settings.PAYMENT_VARIANTS['redsys'][1]['currency]
```